# migrate to react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I try to migrate to the react-router v4, where should I start? For most paths I need authentication and redicert.  I  installed last react-router-dom@next and react-router@next. Now when user is not login redirect to login page, 
also I have login-callback, but have an error 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9998/sockjs-node/472/gnanejj3/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

**application.js**

```
      import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'

import theme from './theme'

import * as AuthActions from './actions/auth'
import Routes from './routes'

export class Application extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        locale: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        messages: React.PropTypes.objectOf(React.PropTypes.string.isRequired).isRequired,
        login: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        redirectToLoginPage: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isLoggedIn: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    };

    render = () =>
        <IntlProvider locale={this.props.locale} messages={this.props.messages}>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(theme)}>
                <Routes />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </IntlProvider>;
}

export default Application
```

**routes.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link ,Redirect, withRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

import Root from './components/root'
import Home from './components/homePage'
import Devices from './components/devices'
import Users from './components/users'
import AddOrEditUser from './components/users/addOrEdit'
import Plans from './components/plans'
import ServerSettings from './components/settings'
import About from './components/aboutPage'
import Patients from './components/patients'
import AddOrEditPatient from './components/patients/addOrEdit'
import Commissioning from './components/commissioning'
import * as AuthActions from './actions/auth'
import redirectToLoginPage from './api/auth'

const Routes = ({isLoggedIn, redirectToLoginPage, login}) =>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' render={({location}) => {
                if (!isLoggedIn)
                    redirectToLoginPage()
                return (
                    <Root>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                            <Route path='/devices' component={Devices} />
                            <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
                            <Route path='/users/add' component={AddOrEditUser}/>
                            <Route path='/users/edit/:personId' component={AddOrEditUser}/>

                            <Patients path='/patients' render={() =>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route path='/add' component={AddOrEditPatient} />
                                        <Route path='/edit/:personId' component={AddOrEditPatient} />
                                    </Switch>
                                }
                            />

                            <Route path='/plans' component={Plans} />
                            <Route path='/commissioning' component={Commissioning} />
                            <Route path='/server-settings' component={ServerSettings} />
                            <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Root>)
            }}
            />
            <Route path='/login-callback' render={() => {
                if (isLoggedIn)
                    login()
                return <Root />
            }}
            />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

Routes.propTypes = {
    // authenticate: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    // processLoginCallback: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    login: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    redirectToLoginPage: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isLoggedIn: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    login: () => dispatch(AuthActions.login()),
    redirectToLoginPage: () => dispatch(AuthActions.redirectToLoginPage()),
})

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
    locale: state.intl.locale,
    messages: state.intl.messages,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Routes)
```

Comment: Nested routes with v4 are a crime on humanity. Spare yourself unrelenting mental anguish and check out [Router5 with React](http://router5.github.io/docs/with-react.html#/inbox) - or find a similar lightweight and sensible alternative that treats nested routes as, hm, very important - not a workaround...

Answer (score 3):

That's a complex question for which a StackOverflow response box is too limiting. I've written a lengthy migration guide. If you're comfortable with react-router v2:v3, this will be a good resource for your migration:

https://medium.com/@francoisz/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a

Answer (score 0):

Since `v4` does not support nested route, this code

```
<Route path='/' render={({location}) => {
        if (!this.props.isLoggedIn)
            this.props.redirectToLoginPage()
        return ( ...
```

will probably stop working

I get around by creating some wrappers for the components .e.g.

```
const enforceLoginValidation = (children) => {
  const fn = ({ match }) => { 
    if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
       this.props.redirectToLoginPage()
       return
    }
    // to pass react-router's match to the children 
    const extendedChild = React.cloneElement(children, { match });
    return extendedChild;
  };
  return fn;
};

...

const HomePage = enforceLoginValidation(
  <Home />
);

....
<Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
```